# Catch exception in angular application when trying to open a specific software installed in local system using windows open

Tags: javascript, angular, window.open

My requirement is to detect if a specific software is installed in my local system from an angular application and if not exists we can ask user to install and if already exists just open that application.

For my scenario i need to open JT2GO software and i have achieved using the below code

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fyzvsb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

[ScreenShot : when software is installed it launches correctly the intended software](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f5KjT.png)

[ScreenShot : When software is not present it gives exception "Failed to launch 'jtcmd1:' because the scheme does not have a registered handler."](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dLnp5.png)

Is there any way we can catch this error in angular application ? (tried try catch and global error handler still unable to catch this error) seems its thrown out of javascript scope

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

this is a quick way to detect an error:

```js
  open() {
      window.open('JTCmd:', '_self').onError = this.onError();
  }

  onError(){
    console.log('this is a test');
  }
```

Comment: you can do a workaround with `window.open('JTCmd:', '_self')?.onError` or `(window.open('JTCmd:', '_self') as any).onError` or an if statement

Comment: Still Error is not captured in this above approach

Comment: Thank for your input. But is there any other way we can capture this error .

Comment: I am not aware of alternatives